# Differences in Herstein Topics in Algebra and Hungerford: Abstract Algebra Introduction

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

Having almost no knowledge of this subject I'm interested to know if Herstein's book in the title would be better for me vs. the Hungerford title mentioned.

Comment: I can't say much about Hungerford's text. I did use Herstein's Topics in Algebra. I like the way Herstein writes. He also includes some pretty hard problems throughout his book but just overall I really enjoyed it as an introductory text.

Comment: has harder problems. Herstein does groups before rings, which I prefer; Tom does rings first, and in general I’d say that his text is a bit less demanding. (Herstein definitely includes harder problems.) Are you comfortable with abstraction? Do you work better when you’re given lots of concrete examples?

Comment: I'm currently working through Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and I would like to think that I can do just fine with abstraction. Concrete examples are nice but books can become bloated too quickly. I definitely prefer more terse books; that being said I am a newcomer to Abstract Algebra.